# MySQL Select multiple rows with almost same value

Tags: python, mysql, select

I am using python and MySQL and I have the following table:

```
id    name    value1    value2
1     a       36041     140636
2     b       36046     140647
3     c       36042     140642
4     d       36042     140645
5     e       36040     140642
```

I want to select all those rows which have almost same value1 and value2 (±2). So based on the table above, I want to select row 3 and row 5 only and arrange them in increasing order of value1. How should I write the SELECT query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this by using self-join:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join table1 t2
on abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1) <= 2
and abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2) <= 2
and t1.id <> t2.id
order by t1.value1
```

And see [***demo***](http://rextester.com/QFWBI78128) in Rextester.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a self join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on abs(t1.value1 - t2.value1) <= 2 and
        abs(t1.value2 - t2.value2) <= 2 and
        t1.id < t2.id
order by t1.value1
```

Comment: It should be t2.value1 and not t2.value21